# printer install not showing in control panel?

Tags: windows-10, installation, script, printer

I've used the following script to install printers, but for some reason it’s not showing up in the control panel but it shows up in the print manager?
I’m using windows 10.

```
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "STR-FRONT-C308-PCL"
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs" -a -r 10.3.10.220 -h 10.3.10.220 -o lpr
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -a -m "KONICA MINOLTA C368SeriesPCL" -v 3 -e "Windows x64" -h "y:\client\10-konica-drivers\c258-c308\64bit\IT5PCL6Winx64_6120EN" -i "y:\client\10-konica-drivers\c258-c308\64bit\IT5PCL6Winx64_6120EN\KOAY1J__.INF"
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs" -a -p "STR-FRONT-C308-PCL" -m "KONICA MINOLTA C368SeriesPCL" -r 10.3.10.220
```

Comment: Does `cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs" -l` lists this printer? Does `cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs" -l` lists this printer port?   Does `cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs" -l` lists this printer driver?

Comment: yeah they all pull in the correct information, i can see the printer in the print management window with all the correct details. It just doesnt show up in the control panel>devices and printers..